# Copy and paste specific set of columns in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, copy-paste

I  have one excel file such as:

```
  1   2  3  4  5
  6   7  8  9  10
  11 12 13 14  15.
```

I want to copy this excel file into notepad ++ in such a format that it shows this format in notepad ++ such as:

```
 1   2 5
 6   7 10
 11 12 15
```

Can anyone help me how can i do this ????

Comment: Have you tried selecting the columns and copying them?

Comment: Without getting enormously complicated, this isn't very do-able.  You're looking for Notepad++ to right-justify numbers, when it's a text editor and doesn't really do columnar justification.  Pasting from Excel to Notepad++ will use tabs between the numbers, which will cause them to line up left-justified.  I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but expecting a text editor to right-justify a column seems to lack understanding of just how text editors work.  Oh, someone could probably write a super-complex macro or program to do it, but it's not worth the effort!

Comment: Please, don't crosspost https://stackoverflow.com/q/54114104/372239 remove this one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Notepad++'s [column mode](https://www.technipages.com/notepad-column-mode).

1. Place your cursor at the beginning position where you want to begin selecting text.
2. Press and hold the “Shift” and “Alt” keys on your keyboard.
3. Continue holding “Shift” and “Alt” while using the “Down” and “Right” arrow keys on your keyboard to select the text as desired.
4. in your case, delete (you can also copy/paste or even search/replace within the selected column(s)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ have [this](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/multi-editing.html) multi-line edit feature..

In Notepad++, just press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (put the cursor on the right of '2' in your pasted text), and drag the selection cursor to the right of '14'.

Then press delete.

Done.

I rarely use this feature, but it is something I like about advanced text editor. AFAIK, MS Visual Studio have this feature too. a search on "multi-line edit feature" will reveal more tough. Anyway.. hope it helps. ( :